# Enabling a button for the first time in IE does not make it tabable (and event handlers don't work)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have an input field that validates for valid zip code:

```
<label class="visiblyHidden" aria-required="true" for="txtZIPCode">ZIP Code</label>
<input type="tel" id="txtZIPCode" class="form-input small" value="${zipvalue}" ${zipdisabled} placeholder="ZIP Code" onkeydown="ZipKeyPress(event,this)" onkeyup="ZipCheckLength(this)" onblur="validateStep()" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

and if it validates it will enable a button via the following function:

```
function EnableNext() {
    $("input:button[title='Next']").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Here is the array of buttons including the Next button:

```
<div class="form-control">
    <span id="wizardError" role="alert" class="formNotes formAlerts" style="display: none;"></span>
    <input type="button" class="btn plainButton" title="Previous" value="Previous" onclick="GoBack()" disabled /> 
    <input type="button" class="btn plainButton" title="Next" value="Next" onclick="SubmitStep()" />
    <input type="button" class="btn plainButton" title="Start Over" value="Start Over" onclick="StartOver()" disabled />
</div>
```

That button has been set up with event handlers that check for the user hitting enter when the button is focused:

```
$("input:button[title='Next']").on('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 32) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.cancel = true;
            SubmitStep();
            return false;       
        }
    });
```

This works fine in Chrome, however in IE, when the button is enabled I still cannot tab to it unless I click with my mouse just before the button and THEN hit tab. But also the event handler doesn't get set propperly, so even if you are focused on the button and hit enter, it will submit the form rather than do what I need it to do - go to another step in our wizard.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think the included JS has any effect on the tabbing of IE.

Comment: Please [include a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you out.

Comment: I've added more parts of my code.  The main issue is when hitting enter on the button, instead of picking up the event handler and executing the SubmitStep() function, it does a Post submit of the form.  Chrome on the other hand works fine, IE(11) does not.

Comment: If the buttons are contained in a form element you could try `event.stopPropagation()` or bind to the `submit` event on the form element and stop its default.

Comment: I tested some code base on the code provided and it's working fine in IE 11 and Edge (also the other major brosers). Which version of IE are you using for testing?

Comment: I'm using IE11.  I added the event.stopPropogation() but I think the overriding issue is that after the Next button is enabled by typing in a valid zip code, I hit tab and the Next button is not in focus, and is never in focus if I just keep hitting tab.  The only way I can get it in focus is to click near it with my mouse, and THEN hit tab.  Then it comes in focus.  It's as if the tab-indexing system does not see the existance of the button until you use the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't ideal but I was able to get this to work by hacking tab highlighting and focus.  I was able to determine that instead of tabbing into the the newly enabled next button after entering a valid zip, it instead tabbed to the dive that surrounded the entire wizard, so I set up another event listener so that when that happens it forces focus on the Next button and also changes the border to look as if it's getting focus in the way it should:

```
function EnableNext() {
$("input:button[title='Next']").removeAttr("disabled");

$("input:button[title='Next']").focus(function () {
    $("input:button[title='Next']").css("border", "1px solid #8CADE2");
});
$("div").focus(function () {
    if (document.activeElement.classList == 'col col-1') {
        $("input:button[title='Next']").focus();
    }
});

$("input:button[title='Next']").blur(function () {
    $("input:button[title='Next']").css("border", "1px solid #CBCBCB");
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need so much code to achieve so. Check this little snippet, works great on IE. Just focus the button after enabling it:

```js
function EnableNext() {
    $("input:button[title='Next']").removeAttr("disabled").focus();
  }
  function SubmitStep() {
    console.log('submit step');
  }
  $("input:button[title='Next']").on('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 32) {
      console.log('key pressed!');
      event.preventDefault();
      SubmitStep();      
    }
  });
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="button" title="Enable" value="Enable" onclick="EnableNext()" /> 
    <input type="button" title="Next" value="Next" onclick="SubmitStep()" disabled />
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```